# How to read scala documentation using reflection

Tags: scala, scaladoc

Is there anyway we can read scala doc comments using reflection. My requirement is to read the @group tag value and use it for counting how many functions are there for each group

Comment: Why do you need reflection? Why not just work with source as a text file?

Comment: ok, i thought using reflection makes it easy. I will try with text file read

Comment: This compiler plugin might be useful: [takezoe/runtime-scaladoc-reader](https://github.com/takezoe/runtime-scaladoc-reader).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't use Scala reflection to access documentation comments. The reason is simple: comments are, almost by definition, *not* part of the program. Therefore, it is logically *impossible* for them to be available via reflection.

In Python, for example, documentation is available from the running program (in fact, even without using reflection), because the documentation is not hidden away in comments, but rather simply assigned to a field of the object that is being documented. Many Lisps (e.g. Clojure), and also Ioke and Seph work that way, too.

In Newspeak, what they call "comments" is available using reflection, but that's because what they call "comments" are not really comments, it is more like arbitrary metadata that can be attached to objects. It is in fact more similar to an annotation in Scala than a comment.

In Scala, documentation is written in comments, and comments are not part of the program (they are *literally* equivalent to whitespace in the [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#whitespace-and-comments)), and therefore, *cannot possibly* be part of the program and thus cannot possibly be accessed via reflection.

Comment: Actually Scala 3 will support comments in tasty reflection. http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/tasty-reflect.html  I see a CommentPicker https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/tree/master/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/core/tasty

Comment: Comments are different from whitespace in Scala because of the weird NL token rule https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters